# How to gracefully avoid divide by zero in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

There are times when you need to divide one metric by another metric.

For example, I'd like to calculate a mean latency like that:

```
rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_sum"}[60s])
/
rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count"}[60s])
```

If there is no activity during the specified time period, the `rate()` in the divider becomes `0` and the result of division becomes `NaN`.
If I do some aggregation over the results (`avg()` or `sum()` or whatever), the whole aggregation result becomes `NaN`.

So I add a check for zero in divider:

```
rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_sum"}[60s])
/
(rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count"}[60s]) > 0)
```

This removes `NaN`s from the result vector. And also tears the line on the graph to shreds.

Let's mark periods of inactivity with `0` value to make the graph continuous again:

```
rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_sum"}[60s])
/
(rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count"}[60s]) > 0)
or
rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count"}[60s]) > bool 0
```

This effectively replaces `NaN`s with `0`, graph is continuous, aggregations work OK.

But resulting query is slightly cumbersome, especially when you need to do more label filtering and do some aggregations over results. Something like that:

```
avg(
    1000 * increase({__name__=~".*_hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_sum", command_group=~"$commandGroup", command_name=~"$commandName", job=~"$service", instance=~"$instance"}[60s])
    /
    (increase({__name__=~".*_hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count", command_group=~"$commandGroup", command_name=~"$commandName", job=~"$service", instance=~"$instance"}[60s]) > 0)
    or
    increase({__name__=~".*_hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count", command_group=~"$commandGroup", command_name=~"$commandName", job=~"$service", instance=~"$instance"}[60s]) > bool 0
) by (command_group, command_name)
```

**Long story short:** Are there any simpler ways to deal with zeros in divider? Or any common practices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If there is no activity during the specified time period, the rate() in the divider becomes 0 and the result of division becomes NaN.

This is the correct behaviour, NaN is what you want the result to be.

> aggregations work OK.

You can't aggregate ratios. You need to aggregate the numerator and denominator separately and then divide.

So:

```
   sum by (command_group, command_name)(rate(hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_sum[5m]))
  /
   sum by (command_group, command_name)(rate(hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count[5m]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got your point. Actually, I was hoping that I overlooked something like `ifNaN(<instant-vector>, default_value_scalar)` that replaces all `NaN`s in the vector, or some language construct that acts this way, and somebody will point me to that. Your variant looks very good, but still needs to be written like `sum(...) / (sum(...) > 0) or sum(...) > bool 0` in case the sum in divider becomes 0 for particular (command_group, command_name) label combination.

Comment: You should not filter with `> 0` here, as it results in missing samples in the time series. NaN is the correct result, as that's what you get when you divide by 0.

Comment: "it results in missing samples" -- that's why I added the `or sum(...) > bool 0` part to the query, to fill the gaps with zeros, representing some default value that's suitable for me in this case.

Comment: The latency during those periods isn't 0 though, it's NaN.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I have a solution for my specific problem:

Having a devision by zero leads to a NaN display - that is fine as a technical result and correct but not what the user wants to see (does not fulfil the business requirement).

So I searched a bit and found a "solution" for my problem in the grafana community:

Surround your problematic value with `max(YOUR_PROLEMATIC_QUERY, or vector(-1))`. An additional value mapping then leads to a useful output.

(Of course you have to adapt the solution to your problem... min/max... vector(42)/vector(101)/vector(...))

**Update (1)**

Okay. However. It seems to be a bit more tricky based on the query. For example I have another query that fails with NaN as a result of a devision by zero. The above solution does not work. I had to surround the query with brackets and added  `> 0 or on() vector(100)`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @eventhorizen's answer, if you have a query as denominator that can sometimes return zero, it can mess up the graph and show infinity where there is no data. You can limit the results to a valid range.

For example the output of this metric is supposed to be between 0 and 1, but it also produces INFINITY when there is no data:

`(1/increase(SOMETIMES_ZERO_QUERY[1m]))`

In this case you can write this instead, so it shows `0` instead of values larger than `100`:

`max((1/increase(SOMETIMES_ZERO_QUERY[1m]))<100 or on() vector(0))`

or if you want `1` as INFINITY:

`max((1/increase(SOMETIMES_ZERO_QUERY[1m]))<100 or on() vector(1))`

Comment: Why is the <100 there?

Comment: @TheJeff it is there to block INFINITY values. you can replace it with any large number.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `> smallest_value` to the query before wrapping it into aggregate function such as [avg()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg), where `smallest_value` is the value, which is smaller than any expected valid result for the inner query. For example:

```
avg((
  rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_sum"}[60s])
  /
  rate({__name__="hystrix_command_latency_total_seconds_count"}[60s])
) > -1e12)
```

Prometheus removes `NaN` values when comparing them to any number with `>` operator. For example, `NaN >bool -1e12` . The same applies to `<` operator as well, e.g. `NaN <bool 1e12` . So either `>` or `<` may be used for filtering `NaN` values before aggregating them with [aggregate functions](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions).

P.S. This trick isn't needed in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html), since VictoriaMtrics automatically skips NaN values when aggregate functions are applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and so had implemented the solution in this way:-

increase({metric query}[2m]) / (increase({problematic zero giving metric query}[2m]))!=0 or on() vector(1) > 150

where I had to check whether the denominator is giving 0 which in turn would give infinity and the graph would be absurd and nonsensical. So in order to avoid this, have put condition `!=0 or vector(1)` so that in case the denominator becomes 0 anytime then its value would be returned as 1 always.